# Unable to boot, bootable USB doesn’t show up

Tags: boot, usb, bios, arch-linux, liveusb

I am trying to make an old computer work again with Arch. I did install arch on it a long time ago but totally forgot what the set up was. Now I am trying to start over.

When I turn it on, it shows me the following screen.
[First Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAN8s.jpg)
When I select either I basically get another screen and the computer is stuck there.

[Outcome of selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMWLn.jpg)

I don’t mind formatting my hard drives and starting over but for the life of me I can’t figure out why my bios is not recognizing my USB stick. It recognizes it occasionally but doesn’t actually log into it. I checked that the live USB is working.

I appreciate any insight. I even tried a live cd and that won't even show up as an option.

My bios settings:
[BIOS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3a1z.jpg)
[BIOS2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLREd.jpg)
[BIOS3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aBME.jpg)
[BIOS4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbK3x.jpg)

EDIT1: I placed my BIOS in config mode by using the jumper system on my motherboard. In this view, my bios consistently recognizes the USB. When I go back to the regular mode, it doesn't.

Comment: Can you check if option "USB Mass Storage Emulation Type" (pic BIOS4) can be set to something like "Auto"?

Comment: @Nassbirne There is an option to set it as AUTO and I did try it that way to. No success.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I did put the flash drive in another computer and made sure it was working. I tried it with two flash drives and both were working.